# How to return the LastDate as a measure

Tags: mdx

This is the expression:

```
WITH 
    MEMBER [Date].[Calendar].[LastDate] AS
        Tail(
          nonempty(
              [Date].[Calendar].MEMBERS,
                [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
            )
        ).Item(0)
    MEMBER [Measures].[MeasureX] AS
        [Date].[Calendar].[LastDate].member_value
SELECT 
  {
        [Measures].[MeasureX]
  } ON COLUMNS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

The result is this:

[image]

How do I configure this so `MeasureX` returns the last date in the `[Date].[Calendar]` dimension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula of a calculated member cannot return a member; you could use an icCube [function](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Declared%20Functions.php) for that ;-) but for SSAS perhaps creating a set of one member might do the trick for you. Then accessing the member could be done using the notation: mySet(0).

Hope that helps.

Comment: `FUNCTION` is something specific to do with `icCube`'s dialect? Is `icCube` opensource freeware?

Comment: ok - so maybe if I use `WITH SET AS` in my script and also `.item(0).item(0)` then it should be ok - I'll test

Comment: icCube is not opensource but there is a free 'community' version available.

Comment: would I still require `SQL-Server analysis services` to build the cubes or is that functionality in the free community version of `icCube`? (looking to try and set up some cubes at home i.e I don't have `SSAS`)

Comment: icCube is a full OLAP server not depending on SSAS.